# Jenkins Python API: get QueueItem by ID

Tags: python, jenkins, jenkins-api

Invoking a job in Jenkins via [jenkinsapi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jenkinsapi/0.2.31) returns a `jenkinsapi.queue.QueueItem` object that represents queued build.

How can I get `QueueItem` object of an already queued build, given `queue_id`? I have tried:

```
j = Jenkins(...)
queue = j.get_queue()
queue_item = queue[queue_id]
```

But that is valid only for about 6-10 seconds, after that `UnknownQueueItem` error is raised.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have to create `QueueItem` manually:

```
j = Jenkins(...)
url = j.base_server_url() + "/queue/item/" + str(queue_id) + "/"
queue_item = jenkinsapi.queue.QueueItem(url, j);
```